# Prestashop back office module

Tags: php, module, prestashop

I`ve tryed to create a Back Office module and a hook in the BackOffice header.

In **admin/theme/header.tpl** file I add a new hook `{HOOK_KALBOS}`, create a new hook in PS_hook table, FronController add this hook.

```
public function install()
{
    return parent::install() && $this->registerHook('displayNav') &&  $this->registerHook('displayKalbos') 
    && $this->registerHook('displayBackOfficeHeader') && $this->registerHook('displayHeader');
}
```

this is install.

```
public function hookDisplayKalbos($params)
{
        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'bolang.tpl');
}
```

But I still can`t see bolang.tpl file content in BO header. Dev mode on show me this:

```
Notice on line 346 in file /public_html/cache/smarty/compile/95/ad/d1/95add145939404fafdefe350fab4ada0465ee07f.file.header.tpl.php
[8] Undefined index: HOOK_KALBOS
```

This is a good way or Should I do this in other way?

Comment: FrontController is for the Front Office pages, not for BackOffice. What is the PrestaShop version?

Comment: @user3047312 Why do you want to create a module in the Back Office header, please be more specific, because the Back Office is just to control the behavior of your shop.